# Does Shield of Faith persist on a druid who uses Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape

If *shield of faith* is cast on a druid and the druid then uses *wild shape* to change into say a tiger, will *shield of faith* persist? Does it dissipate? Or does the effect "disappear" until the druid reverts?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99436/how-does-bestow-curse-on-a-polymorphed-creature-work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The effect persists until it times out (as long as the caster maintains concentration)**

There is only one rule listed under Wild Shape regarding spell usage. From the [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/classes/druid/#Wild_Shape):

> ...
>
> - You can’t cast spells, and your ability to speak or take any action that requires hands is limited to the capabilities of your beast form. Transforming doesn’t break your concentration on a spell you’ve already cast, however, or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell, such as call lightning, that you’ve already cast.
>
> ...

This states that *you* cannot cast spells while in beast form, but makes no mention of others casting spells on you, and indicates that spells cast on you remain active. If you are the caster you may cast Shield of Faith before using Wild Shape, and then maintain concentration as normal while in beast form - similar to Call Lightning in the given example.